# How to get if a user is admin of a page (isAdmin) using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the old REST API, you could do call `https://api.facebook.com/method/pages.isAdmin` to know if a user was the admin of a given page.

How can you do that using the Graph API? I can't find anything about it in the documentation and start to wonder if it's even possible.

Comment: @Peter bailey: No, I'm actually using Facebooker for Ruby on Rails, but I'd say that this problem is tech agnostic since it's just calling an URL and parsing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to view that info in the [accounts connection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#impersonation)

Comment: oh that's pretty cool, thanks! It's too bad that you have to get all the pages of a user just to check if he's admin of one page though...

Comment: link is no longer valid, probably it's deprecated by now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$session_key = $_REQUEST['fb_sig_session_key'];//maybe there is a better way to get this
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$is_admin = $facebook->api(array('method'=>'pages.isadmin', 'page_id'=>'YOUR_PAGE_ID', 'session_key'=>$session_key, 'access_token'=>$access_token));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to run FQL on [page_admin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin) table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$page=$facebook->api('/[PAGE ID]?fields=access_token');
if (!$page['access_token'])
    echo "is not admin";
```

Answer (score 0):

From FB docs: `GET` `/v2.2/{page-id}/roles/{user-id}`

Also see [How can i get the admins user id of a page in facebook.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001033/how-can-i-get-the-admins-user-id-of-a-page-in-facebook/38839294).