# How do I get the list of facebook apps a user is an admin of using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

Am using the Facebook Ads API to run ads. For running **Mobile App Ads**, I need to retrieve the apps which the logged in User is an admin of. I couldn't figure out from the documentation as to how to get this list of apps. Some stack overflow threads ([How to get if a user is admin of a page (isAdmin) using the Facebook Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627976/how-to-get-if-a-user-is-admin-of-a-page-isadmin-using-the-facebook-graph-api)) suggest requesting **/me/accounts** , but the just returns a list of facebook pages the user is an admin of. Could someone suggest some documentation in this direction?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API call `/me/applications/developer` returns all applications of which the user is an admin.

Read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/applications/developer

Comment: This returns applications for which the user is a developer. I want to retrieve apps for which the user is an admin. Any idea on how that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn’t seem to be possible with the current API v2.0 – but it is with FQL, using the [`app_role`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/app_role) table:

```
SELECT application_id FROM app_role
  WHERE developer_id = me() AND role = 'administrators'
```

[Test it in Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20application_id%20from%20app_role%20where%20developer_id%20%3D%20me%28%29%20and%20role%20%3D%20%27administrators%27)

(And yes, FQL is deprecated, but it will still be around for at least two years. And before they completely shut it off, they will implement query-like features in a future API version according to what I’ve heard from FB employees.)